# Trying to list files/folders WITHOUT a specific directory

Tags: windows, command, prompt, dir

I'm trying to get a file and directory listing for a web site I inherited.  I opened a Windows command prompt (I'm using Windows 7) and entered the following command:
dir /o:gn /s > filename.txt.

For the most part, it does what I want.  HOWEVER, it also includes the annoying _notes directories that DreamWeaver leaves behind -- which I DON'T want!!!!!!!

I have to slog through thousands of files and directories, and I could care less about the _notes directories (or anything in them).  Editing my results is going to take way too long, and I don't have time to do that.

Is there any way to supress specific files/directories from a DIR command?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd just do it like this:

```
for /R %f in (*) do @echo %f >> allfiles.txt
grep -v \\_notes\\ allfiles.txt > files.txt
```

If you don't have `grep` then you should get it and learn how to use it. I recommend the version from [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, when you export the list of files use a vim macro to remove the directories you do not want.
Something like (I did not test this):
qq/_notes^Mddq@q

note: replace ^M with the Enter key